# Connect Facebook Account to Django User

Tags: django-allauth

I'm trying to permanently connect a fb account to a standard user account. Users will login using their own site specific credentials, connect to their fb account and then we will be able to make graph calls to fb without ever having to re-authenticate with fb again.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
<a href ="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method='js_sdk' process='connect' %}">Facebook connect</a>
```

This only stores a short term token in the database and every time the user logs out of fb this is invalidated and they have to re-authenticate.

My question is:

How do I get a long term token?

Is this supported by all-auth out of the box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Here's a function that will get a long life token from a short life token, which you can store in the SocialToken table and then use with all subsequent FB.api calls :

```
def get_long_life_token(short_life_token):

    import urllib
    import re

    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<id>&client_secret=<secret>&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=" + str(short_life_token) 

    try:
        data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        data = re.search('access_token=(.+?)&expires=', data).group(1)
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```